# How many integer solutions are there of the equation $|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+\cdots +|x_{k}|=n$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

> How many solutions are there to the equation
>
> $$|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+\cdots +|x_{k}|=n$$
>
> for $n,k\in \mathbb N$ and $\forall\ 1\leq i\leq k,\ x_{i}\in \mathbb Z$?

Any ideas? I don't know how to approach this question. (all I know that if my  $ x_{i}$'s were in $\mathbb N$ the solution would be $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$  )

Comment: i think we need to multiply by a factor of $2^k$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar is correct. Any solution with all $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$ corresponds to $2^k$ different solutions with $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, one for each choice of assigning $+$ or $-$ to each $x_i$. E.g., for the solution $|1|+|2|+|3|=6$, you also have the $2^3-1=7$ other solutions $|1|+|2|+|-3|=6$, $|1|+|-2|+|3|=6$, $|-1|+|2|+|3|=6$, $|1|+|-2|+|-3|=6$, $|-1|+|2|+|-3|=6$, $|-1|+|-2|+|3|=6$, and $|-1|+|-2|+|-3|=6$.

Comment: @kccu Is that entirely right? If $x_1=0$, for instance, then the remaining $k-1$ terms sum to $n$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Ah that's a very good point. I was assuming $\mathbb{N}$ meant nonnegative integers. Even so, my comment misses all the solutions with some $x_i=0$.

Answer (score 8):

It is a simple variation on [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The number of solutions of
$$ x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k = n $$
with $x_i\in\mathbb{N}^+$ is given by the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k$, i.e. by $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, so the number of solutions of
$$\left|x_1\right|+\ldots +\left|x_k\right| = n$$

with $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is given by $2^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. If we take the number of zero variables as a parameter, we get that the number of solutions of
$$ \left|x_1\right|+\ldots +\left|x_k\right| = n $$
with $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is given by:

> $$ \sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{k-h}\binom{n-1}{h-1}2^h. $$

The connection with the GFs found by Felix and Semiclassical lies here:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h}2^h [x^{n-h}]\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^h &=& \sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h}[x^n]\left(\frac{2x}{1-x}\right)^h\\&=&[x^n]\left(1+\frac{2x}{1-x}\right)^k\\&=&[x^n]\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^k.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Is there an obvious way to relate this result with what Felix got in his answer? I'd assumed that the answer found by finding the GF would lead to here, but it's not obvious to me how it does.

Comment: @Semiclassical: well, my last sum can be read as the coefficient of $x^k$ in the product between $2x(1+2x)^{n-1}$ and $(1+x)^k$ (if I am not wrong), so some trivial manipulations should give your equivalent GF and Felix' formula as well.

Comment: @Semiclassical: oh, sure: $$ \frac{1+t}{1-t}=1+2t+2t^2+\ldots=1+\frac{2t}{1-t}$$ does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\delta_{\ell\ell'}}$ is the *Kronecker Delta* which is equal to $\ds{1}$ if $\ds{\ell = \ell'}$ and $\ds{0}$ otherwise. The following multiple sum 'counts' $\ds{1}$ each time $\ds{\verts{x_{1}} + \cdots + \verts{x_{k}} = n}$.
>   So,

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{x_{1} = -\infty}^{\infty}\cdots
\sum_{x_{k} = -\infty}^{\infty}
\delta_{\verts{x_{1}} + \cdots + \verts{x_{k}}\,,\,n}} =
\sum_{x_{i} = -\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{x_{k} = -\infty}^{\infty}\
\overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{n + 1 - \verts{x_{1}} - \cdots - \verts{x_{k}}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\delta_{\verts{x_{1}} + \cdots + \verts{x_{k}}\,,\,n}}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{n + 1}}
\sum_{x_{1} = -\infty}^{\infty}z^{\verts{x_{1}}}\cdots
\sum_{x_{k} = -\infty}^{\infty}z^{\verts{x_{k}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{n + 1}}\,\pars{1 + 2\,{z \over 1 - z}}^{k}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{n + 1}}\,\pars{1 - z}^{-k}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{n + 1}}\,\
\overbrace{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-k \choose j}\pars{-z}^{j}}^{\ds{\pars{1 - z}^{-k}}}\
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] = &\
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-k \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{n + 1 - j}}\,\
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{{k \choose n - j}}} =
\sum_{j = n - k}^{n}{k + j - 1 \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j}\pars{-1}^{j}
{k \choose n - j}
\\[3mm] & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k + j + n - k - 1 \choose j + n - k}
{k \choose n - j - n + k} =
\color{#f00}{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{j + n - 1 \choose k - 1}{k \choose  j}}
\end{align}

Comment: Insanely weird answer, +1.

Answer (score 2):

A generating-function solution is straightforward. For each $|x_j|$, every positive $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ occurs as both $x_j=n$ and $x_j=-n$; on the other hand, $|x_j|=0$ requires $x_j=0$. This sequence is generated by $$1+2t+2t^2+\cdots =(1+t)(1-t)^{-1}.$$ (This can be checked by multiplying both sides by $1-t$.)

Counting the solutions to $\sum_{j=1}^k |x_j|=n$ then amounts to finding the  coefficient of $t^n$ in $\left(\dfrac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^k.$ But these can be found as the Cauchy product of the coefficients of $(1+t)^k$ and $(1-t)^{-k}$, each of which can be found by the binomial theorem. This should yield the same answer as obtained by Jack D'Aurizio; I leave the remaining details to the interested reader.

Comment: "coefficent of $t^k$" should be $t^n$ I think

Comment: Yep. Fixed @DPoole

Comment: I was struggling with the final sum ( in my answer ) to get a closed form. However, your answer convinced me that was no way to find it ( "for the time being" ? ).